# sendFormByEmail(e) returning undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have this code to send Google Form responses to email.

```
 function sendFormByEmail(e) {   
  Logger.log("e: " + e);
  var email = "email@gmail.com"; 
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
  var message = "";
  var subject = "New Hire Form Submission: ";

  for(var i in headers) 
    message += headers[i] + ': '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";     
 
  // Insert variables from the spreadsheet into the subject.
  // This creates an email subject like "New Hire: Jane Doe - starts 4/23/2013"
  subject += e.namedValues[headers[2]].toString() + " - starts " + e.namedValues[headers[15]].toString();

  // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}
```

This is tied to the spreadsheet not the form and e is returning undefined. I saw someone else have this issue and disabling the new Chrome V8 worked for them but is not working for me.

[trigger settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7MD9.png)

Comment: Have you installed this `sendFormByEmail` function as an `onSubmitForm` trigger ? Also function is supposed to be a trigger function. You don't execute it manually. It is executed when the form is submitted.

Comment: Yes it is installed, added an image of the trigger settings to the original post

Comment: There are two form submit trigger are you using the one for spreadsheets?

Comment: How do I double check? I am fairly confident I am using the one for spreadsheets. I specified 'From spreadsheet' for 'Select event source' and opened app script from the spreadsheet.

Comment: What line is is failing on?

Comment: Failing on line 10: " message += headers[i] + ': '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";" with the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined."

Comment: What is the output of `Logger.log("e: " + e);`? Are you trying to run the code manually by pressing the "play" button?

Comment: If I run it using the play button it is [20-10-22 07:48:21:159 PDT] e: undefined. I have been testing by submitting a form and the form entry appears on the spreadsheet but appears as a failed execution on the trigger page. The headers appear correctly when I click debug while e is still undefined.

Comment: What ist he error message of the failed execution? Did you rename the funciton after you created the trigger? (if so, please delete the trigger and install a new one)

Answer (score 1):

By the time the function is called, the data is already in the spreadsheet, so you could just read the last now

```
var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
var columns = s.getLastColumn()
var range = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, columns).getValues();
```